# What is the % doing in this snippet of code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modulo

I came across a line of code that confused me:

```
return [cellSize[indexPath.item % 2] CGSizeValue];
```

More specifically: `[indexPath.item % 2]`

The only thing I found about `%` in Xcode mostly involve `%@, %f, etc...` and escaping % in string. I also know about ternary but thats not what this is, is it?
Can someone explain what that line is doing?

More context if needed:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CQTaskPhotosCVCell *cell = (CQTaskPhotosCVCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [cellSize[indexPath.item % 2] CGSizeValue];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> return [cellSize[indexPath.item % 2] CGSizeValue];

The `%` is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (remainder after division).

Taking `% 2` is a common way to select even vs. odd rows, e.g. to alternate coloring. In your case, it seems to be selecting from two distinct cell sizes (based on the name of the variable cellSize).

Comment: just curious, if i was to do something like ` (pseudo code) if ([indexPath.item % 2] ) { cell.color = red}` would that make every other cell red? I'm mobile so i can't tinker

Comment: Yes, that's how I commonly see that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

For even numbered `indexPath.items`, the code is using `cellSize[0]` to determine the size for the item at the `indexPath`. For odd numbered `indexPath.items`, the code is using `cellSize[1]`.

`%` is the modulo operator (provides the remainder after integer division). When dividing by 2, the remainder will always be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is modulo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another

Answer (score 0):

It is the modulo operator and calculates the remainder of a division operation.

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.5.5:5